# Why would someone try viewing the site with unsupported languages?

Tags: language

Our site is receiving page views with strange browser locales. The most recent, on Sunday, included the following;

- vi_VN
- vi_VI
- zh_SG
- as_AS
- bn_BN
- mr_MR
- kn_KN
- or_OR
- ml_ML
- pa_PA
- pa_IN
- pa_PK
- ta_TA
- te_TE

The UA string is;

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0
```

We can't see any malicious input being attempted but we don't currently support any locales besides en_GB and en_US. The IP is located in Arizona.

<strike>Has anyone experienced this before? If so, what was the motivation behind it?</strike>
Is this something I should be concerned about?

Comment: Does the user agent reveal anything?

Comment: I haven't got access to the UA strings at this time, I will post them as soon as I get hold of them. Thanks

Comment: It could be that your visitors don't speak English as a first language. Or it could be a clever bot/cache-server trying to detect whether you serve UA-dependent content.

Comment: Please respond with more information so that this question can be reopened.

Comment: One of my colleagues thinks it could be as simple as a Linux install with all the language packs installed.

Comment: Are all these locales on a single request, as opposed to on separate requests?

Comment: They are in a single request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox has the ability to send many languages.  This feature is designed such that somebody can specify which language(s) they understand and the web server can choose which to display.

In Firefox this is available under "Preferences" -> "Content" -> "Languages" -> "Choose".  It appears that in this case a user has added a ton of languages here.  Probably ones that they don't actually speak.  I can do the same thing if I want to:

[image]

Comment: That would certainly explain what's been going on. Thank you.